# CSS como fazer ícone piscar ir e voltar?

Tags: css

Olá quero uma ajuda nesse código do CSS quero que quando a pessoa passe o mouse em cima do ngç, o ícone(imagem ex:coração) apareça e quando mouse sair da quele local o ícone(imagem ex:coração) suma, tentei usa display:none mas não deu certo

aqui esta o css:

```
.ask-data .action a.ask-share, .ask-data .action a.ask-like {
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding: 5px 4px 4px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.ask-data i.like {
    background-image: url("../img/ask.png?x=2");
    background-position: -73px -93px;
}
.ask-data i.like:hover {
    background-image: url("../img/ask.png?x=2");
    background-position: -73px -108px;
}
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor seu problema

Comment: @MarceloBatista Sim, olha tenho um site nele tem um ícone que e uma bandeira, quero fazer ela sumir e aparecer quando alguém passa o mouse em cima, tendeu?

Comment: O que é o "ngç," vc tem o HTML, pode facilitar as coisas.

Comment: @hugocsl quero fazer que nem esse site askmee.tk/zero0 a bandeira nas pergunta passa o mouse em cima veja como aparece

Answer (score 0):

Use o elemento `opacity`, pois ele não some com o elemento, apenas esconde, sendo possível usar `listeners`, lembrando que `opacity` aceita somente o `alpha`, ou seja, vai de 0 à 1.

```
.ask-data i.like {
    opacity: 0;
}
.ask-data i.like:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: não e isso, olha esse site http://askmee.tk/zero0 a bandeira nas pergunta passa o mouse em cima veja como aparece

Comment: Então você quer mudar a cor?

Comment: Ali ele usa uma imagem se vc for ver quero fazer que icone apareça quando mouse chega na quela areá sem precisar esta exatamente em cima do icone

Comment: neste caso você precisa que o ícone seja filho do container. Então o código seria mais ou menos assim: `.container:hover i.like {opacity: 1; }`, pois o evento de sobreposição está vinculado ao container, e não ao item.